# df[ df['sex'] == 'Male' ] returns empty dataframe

Tags: pandas

df is a DataFrame of the Adult data set.  I tried to extract rows where the "sex" column has value "Male" with the code: df[ df['sex'] == 'Male' ]; however, it returns empty data frame with only the column names showing. What might be the issue (I am new to Pandas)?

Comment: Run `df.sex = df.sex.str.strip()` first and  then your code

Comment: Could you give an example of the dataframe?

Comment: In addition to use 'strip' as COLDSPEED suggested, check as well whether all the values in the sex column have the first character in upper case and the others in lower case

Comment: Thanks COLDSPEED for the answer, and it worked!  I knew what the problem was -- strings got converted to 'Object', thus failed in comparison.  I tried ALL suggestions I could found, and none worked including: df.sex = df.sex.str ;-).... thanks again!